# ArcPy merge output only has the first feature class in list

Tags: arcpy, merge, list, dictionary

I have a script that generates several feature classes. I use a function to create the feature classes within a loop. The loop outputs a dictionary with a name string as key and the feature class path as the value.

I then need to select some features from each of those feature classes and merge them into a single feature class. To do this, I ran a loop to select by the query and append the resulting feature layer into a list so I could merge the list.

However, when I run that list through the Merge tool, my output only takes the first item in the list instead of merging all the feature layers in the list. Does anyone know why this is the resulting output? I left out the function and some details to shorten the code segment below, it should have everything relevant.

```
outputlist = {}
#For each key and value in the input dictionary...
for key, value in fcdict.items():
    outputlist[value] = genGrid(key, value, wsGDB) 

# Create blank list for loop purposes    
lyrList = []
# SQL query to only select gridcode greater than or equal to 6
query = "gridcode >= 6"
# Set variable to final output path and name
output_name = os.path.join(wsGDB, "CrimePolys")
# For each key and value in the output list...
for key, value in outputlist.items():
    # Create a feature layer based on the dictionary
    fc_lyr = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(value, key)
    # Add selection to that feature layer
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc_lyr, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", query)
    # Append that selected feature layer to a list
    lyrList.append(fc_lyr)
# Merge all files in the feature layer list
arcpy.Merge_management([lyrList], output_name)
```

I couldn't figure out a way to do this without copying the selected features to a new feature class. I'm working with small numbers of features (less than 100 total) so its not a roadblock for me. I don't know if its pythonic to generate so much intermediate data that then has to get deleted at the end of the script though.

Comment: The layer list parameter is a list of layer *names*, not a list of list of results. I'm surprised that doesn't just report an error.

Comment: Honestly, I expected it to error on that too since its not a list of actual feature classes but instead just names. But you can't apply a selection on just a feature class so...figured I'd try it.

Comment: To solve this you need to show what is stored your `outputlist` dictionary, by the way calling a dictionary a list is not helpful...

Comment: The first thing that jumps out to me is that `lyrList` is a list, but you're wrapping that list in another list when you pass it into `Merge_management()`